# visual studio code: expand snippet within snippet

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

When I am inside a snippet expansion say:

```
\(<tab>
```

I will go into the snippet

```
\(<cursor here>\)<cursor waiting to jump to here>
```

But during this time, I cannot expand any other snippet or get any completion, until I finished the snippet (jump to the final location of the snippet). 
Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer: all you need to do is to set `editor.suggest.snippetsPreventQuickSuggestions` to false